# Python: Append Pandas DataFrame column by column with conditional indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, conditional-statements

After days of struggling I am now reaching out to the community.

I have on the one side generated a list of values:

```
NoColoniesRandom = 
['BB1.3', 'BB1.6', 'BB1.10', 'BB1.12', 'BB1.14', 'BB1.16', 'BB1.20', 'BB1.21', 'BB1.23', 'BB1.24', 'BB1.30', 'BB1.31', 'BB1.32', 'BB1.33', 'BB1.34', 'BB1.35', 'BB1.38', 'BB1.41', 'BB1.44', 'BB1.45', 'BB1.46', 'BB1.47', 'BB1.48', 'BB2.1', 'BB2.2', 'BB2.3', 'BB2.4', 'BB2.5', 'BB2.6', 'BB2.7', 'BB2.8', 'BB2.9', 'BB2.10', 'BB2.11', 'BB2.12', 'BB2.13', 'BB2.14', 'BB2.15', 'BB2.16', 'BB2.17', 'BB2.18', 'BB2.19', 'BB2.20', 'BB2.21', 'BB2.22', 'BB2.23', 'H1.11', 'H1.22', 'H1.23', 'H1.28', 'H1.29', 'H1.33', 'H1.37', 'H1.46', 'H1.65', 'H1.68', 'H1.69', 'H1.72', 'H1.73', 'H1.77', 'H1.80', 'H1.84', 'H1.88', 'H1.93', 'H1.104', 'H1.106', 'H1.110', 'H1.114', 'H1.119', 'H2.3', 'H2.4', 'H2.5', 'H2.6', 'H2.7', 'H2.8', 'H2.10', 'H2.11', 'H2.12', 'H2.13', 'H2.15', 'H2.16', 'H2.17', 'H2.18', 'H2.19', 'H2.20', 'H2.21', 'H2.22', 'H2.23', 'H2.24', 'H2.25', 'H2.27', 'H2.28', 'PM1.6', 'PM1.19', 'PM1.22', 'PM1.36', 'PM1.43', 'PM1.54', 'PM1.56', 'PM1.58', 'PM1.64', 'PM1.77', 'PM1.87', 'PM1.104', 'PM1.109', 'PM1.115', 'PM1.125', 'PM1.142', 'PM1.146', 'PM1.147', 'PM1.148', 'PM1.160', 'PM1.161', 'PM1.165', 'PM1.169', 'PM2.8', 'PM2.12', 'PM2.22', 'PM2.27', 'PM2.35', 'PM2.45', 'PM2.48', 'PM2.50', 'PM2.51', 'PM2.53', 'PM2.54', 'PM2.58', 'PM2.69', 'PM2.75', 'PM2.77', 'PM2.90', 'PM2.97', 'PM2.101', 'PM2.107', 'PM2.109', 'PM2.120', 'PM2.125', 'PM2.135']
```

On the other side I have my DataFrame where one column ('NC1') has the same values, but including some more.

I want to sort out (delete/drop) all the columns where the value in df['NC1'] is in my list NoColoniesRandom.

Biggest issues I have experienced: not able to condition index a series with an ambiguous value; getting the indexes to drop the columns; ... I also tried creating a new empty data frame trying to append it by the columns where the conditions will be true. Hope somebody can help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isin()` and boolean indexing to delete/drop all values in `df['NC1']` which are in your list `NoColoniesRandom`.

```py
m = df['NC1'].isin(NoColoniesRandom)
df_ = df[~m]
```

Comment: thank you, man! afterwards it's mostly so easy just using one function, unless you know the function! thanks a lot, it solved my issue!